# Logic - Translate a Math Statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I need to translate the given statement into propositional logic using the propositions provided.

To use the wireless network in the airport you must pay the daily fee unless you are a subscriber to the service. Express your answer in terms of

$\;w:\;$ “You can use the wireless network in the airport,”

$\;d:\;$ “You pay the daily fee,” and

$\;s:\;$ “You are a subscriber to the service.”

Comment: $\mathrm{ofw}\Rightarrow(\mathrm{d}\vee\mathrm{s})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\text{If }\; w, \;\text{then}\; (d \;\text{or}\; s),\;\text{ which is equivalent to }\; w {\it \text{ only if}}\;\; (d \;\text{or}\; s).\;$$ and can be expressed symbolically as the proposition: $$w \rightarrow(d \lor s)$$

Since you used the tag "predicate calculus" and if you mean for the variables to represent predicates, then define a constant to represent "you": $y:= \text{ you}$

$$w(y) \rightarrow (d(y) \lor s(y))$$

Or if we are stating a universal policy, applying to the domain of all airport visitors, then we have $$\forall x\,\Big(w(x) \rightarrow (d(x)\lor s(x))\Big)$$

This might make more sense if we consider the logically equivalent contrapositive of the quantified expression:

$$\forall x\,\Big(\lnot(d(x) \lor s(x)) \rightarrow \lnot w(x)\Big)\equiv \forall x\,\Big((\lnot d(x) \land \lnot s(x)) \rightarrow \lnot w(x)\Big)$$

If you do not pay the daily fee and you are not a subscriber, then you cannot use the wireless service in the airport.

Comment: Doesn't "you must pay the daily fee unless you are a subscriber to the service" imply they are mutually exclusive, rather than inclusive?

Comment: @JohnH In natural language, perhaps, but in logic, unless otherwise specified, we know nothing about what happens when you are a subscriber, only what happens when you aren't a subscriber.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Thanks a lot!